# jQuery contains selector to search for multiple-strings when grouping divs to a sub-group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bunch of divs in an container where several of the divs have similar text - and I want them  to be grouped in subgropus. This works great for divs that all have a string in common like this:

```
$( ".datainfo:contains('computer')" ).wrapAll( "<div       class='newcontainer' />");
```

But then I have three divs that contains text that are unique for each div - N1, N2 and N3.

How do I group those together? I tried this, that I thought would work but it isn't..

```
$('.datainfo:contains("N1"):contains("N2"):contains("N3")').wrapAll( "<div class='newcontainer2'/>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector you use demands that `.datainfo` must contain 'N1', 'N2' **and** 'N3'. Instead, comma separate them, to select all `.datainfo` that contains either one of them:

```
$('.datainfo:contains("N1"), .datainfo:contains("N2"), .datainfo:contains("N3")').wrapAll( "<div class='newcontainer2'/>");
```

Comment: Ah. for some reason it only pulled the first div into the container and left the others out.

Answer (score 1):

**JS**

```
$('.datainfo:contains("N1"),.datainfo:contains("N2"),.datainfo:contains("N3")')
```

Try the above selctor hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter()`, imho, better for readability:

```
$('.datainfo').filter(':contains("N1"), :contains("N2"), :contains("N3")').wrapAll("<div class='newcontainer2'/>");
```